# Is there any routes mechanism or anything for replacement in Taipy?

Tags: routes, taipy

I'm new for Taipy. I want to make a simple login process: the default page is login page, after login success, go to the main page.
But only single page/multiple pages introduction on Taipy official document pages.

Is there any solution for replacement in Taipy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [here](https://github.com/Avaiga/taipy/discussions/348) a simple login example. Pages are already built and are not protected. You could use [partials](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/pages/#partials) to change pages from empty to what they should look like to hide their content.

The mechanism of [authentication, authorization, protected pages](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/auth/), and so on is directly integrated into [Taipy Enterprise](https://www.taipy.io/products/enterprise).

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui, notify


login_open = True
username = ''
password = ''


dialog_md = """
<|{login_open}|dialog|title=Login|labels=Create account|on_action=create_account|width=30%|
**Username**
<|{username}|input|label=Username|class_name=fullwidth|>

**Password**
<|{password}|input|password|label=Password|class_name=fullwidth|>

<br/>
<|Sign in|button|class_name=fullwidth plain|on_action=login|>
|>
"""


def create_account(state):
    notify(state, "info", "Creating account...")
    # Put your own logic to create an account
    # Maybe, by opening another dialog
    state.username = "Taipy"
    state.password = "password"
    notify(state, "success", "Account created!")


def login(state):
    # Put your own authentication system here
    if state.username == "Taipy" and state.password == "password":
        state.login_open = False
        notify(state, "success", "Logged in!")
    else:
        notify(state, "error", "Wrong username or password!")


pages = {"/": dialog_md,
         "Home": "# Taipy application"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Gui(pages=pages).run()
```

[image: Login example]

Comment: Hi, Florian. It's a pretty good way by using dialog. It works. Thanks for your help! 

BTW, I'm trying to modify the proected field '_config.pages' of 'Gui' class, after that, reload Gui to remove login page. It's triky.... : (